# How to change the terminal to the current directory in visual studio code ? (hotkey)

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, hotkeys

In class we had a hotkey for using the terminal with the currently choosen directory. I fixed an issue now with the debugger and everything seems to run smoothly now. Yet, what hotkey fixes this issue?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: If I use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command the terminal opens just as toggle terminal. But, the directory is not opening.

Answer (score 49):

With VSCode 1.39 (Sept. 2019), no more plugin needed.
You now can "[Open new terminals with custom working directories](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39#_open-new-terminals-with-custom-working-directories)"

> There is a new command that allows the creation of terminals with a **custom current working directory** (`cwd`):
>
> ```
> {
>   "key": "cmd+shift+c",
>   "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
>   "args": {
>     "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You can create your own keyboard shortcuts to open new terminals in any number of handy working directories.
> The `cwd` value can either be a normal path or a [variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

---

[ChrisoLosoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12316388/chrisolosoph) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668151/how-to-change-the-terminal-to-the-current-directory-in-visual-studio-code-hot/58311671#comment136932160_58311671):

> What to do with the pasted code snippet:
>
> - press <kbd>F1</kbd>,
> - <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and
> - select "`Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`"
> - and paste it there.

Comment: Haven't needed a plugin to change the current terminal working directory for a few months.

Comment: @Mark Agreed. This is for creating a *new* terminal.

Comment: Yes, as detailed in my linked answer ;>}

Comment: Thanks, but for a newbie coming from Atom, what do I actually have to do?! Where is that snippet?

Comment: @Pithikos You can see it in action in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156461. But that issue also illustrates it might not always work as well as expected.

Comment: The shortcut mentioned above is not working for me, - `CTRL+Shift+H` is already a keyboard shortcut for `workbench.action.replaceInFiles`. (Probably a change in newer VS Code versions)

Comment: @Gangula Thank you for the feedback. I believe this is now Ctrl+Shift+c.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+c` opens Windows Command prompt (cmd), it doesn't open the integrated terminal. Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Gangula Yes it is. I did not found `newWithCwd` with the latest VSCode versions.

Comment: If others didn't understand either, what to do with the pasted code snippet: press F1, enter and select "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" and paste it there.

Comment: @ChrisoLosoph Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 26):

For a hotkey to quickly set your terminal folder to your current directory, see [How to quickly change shell folder to match the currently open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218958/how-to-quickly-change-shell-folder-to-match-the-currently-open-file/56222855#56222855)

```
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {"text": "cd '${fileDirname}'\u000D"}
},
```

**This will change your current terminal**, not open a new terminal - if you want to do that see the link above as well for the new command recently added to vscode.

**Note that on windows, you must use the following instead:**

```
"args": {"text": "cd /d \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"}
```

This is because on Windows, the `/d` parameter must be used with `cd` to switch drives.

Comment: This will also change focus (copy paste to understand)

    {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+'",
      "command": "runCommands",
      "args": {
        "commands": [
          "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
          { "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence", "args": { "text": "cd '${fileDirname}'\u000D" } }
        ]
      }
    },

Answer (score 11):

By default, the terminal will open at the folder that is opened in the Explorer. The hotkey for that depends on your operating system, in my case, on macOS, it's <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, on Windows I think it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>.

If you want to open at a specific folder you can change that behaviour with this setting:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.cwd": "/home/user"
}
```

If you want to open at the current file's directory you can install an extension like [Terminal Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here).

You can change the shortcuts/hotkeys for many actions on Code. For that open the Keyboard Shortcuts editor under `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` and search for `Toggle Integrated Terminal`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Our professor showed us a hotkey, so I want to ask now in the industry would people use a hotkey or terminal here.

Is there not a hotkey I can set ? I found two more convenient ways for me. 

Where do I add this in the json.file for user settings ?

Comment: Hi @DimitriWilliams, I edited my answer, check it out. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi @Diogo Rocha this is exactly what is not working. I can open the terminal, but not the directory where I opened the file, where I am writing code.

I changed  File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and search for Toggle Integrated Terminal. To a Key Command / Hotkey and it only opens the workspace folder, not the folder with the code inside the terminal.

Comment: So I would suggest you to install the "Terminal Here" extension, and set a custom keyboard shortcut for that.

Comment: That helped and worked immediately, I will remember this till the end of the extension. Thank you!