# How to quickly change shell folder to match the currently open file

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

With single file opened in vscode, when I open integrated Powershell it always starts in my `$HOME` folder.

Is there any way to quickly switch to the directory of the currently shown file without having to manually `cd` into it?

Something like `cd $vsCurrentFileDirectory`.

Currently, I right click the tab and copy path then `cd (Split-Path <CTRL-v>)`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**EDIT**: A new command will be added in **v1.39** to make this more straightforward, see [release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_39.md#open-new-terminals-with-custom-working-directories).  The example keybinding given is:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+h",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
    "args": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
}
```

which does indeed work in the Insider's Build.  This will create a **new terminal** though, not modify an existing terminal.

---

[**Original Answer**]: This will **change the current terminal**.

You can set up a keybinding to do this pretty easily:

```
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {"text": "cd '${fileDirname}'\u000D"}
},
```

The `\u000D` is a return so the command triggers immediately.

Also note that I put the `'${fileDirname}'` in quotes in case your directory name has spaces in it.

The keybinding will work whether focus is in the terminal or the file.

---

Suggested edit to be tested :

**Note that on windows, you must use the following instead:**

```
"args": {"text": "cd /d \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"}
```

This is because on Windows, the `/d` parameter must be used with `cd` to switch drives.

---

Also see [shortcut to change directory in Powershell and cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893791/vs-code-shortcut-to-change-the-current-directory-in-the-powershell-console-to) for additional info in case you are changing drive letters and escaping double quotes in Powershell.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {"text": "cd \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"}
}
```

with discussion of the `/d` flag.  Thanks to @skataben for the additional info.

---

Alternatively, there is an extension to do this:  [terminal-here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here), but the keybinding actually works faster.  The `sendSequence` and variable substitution functionality was not available when that extension was created.

Finally, if you right-click on a folder in the explorer, there is an `Open in Terminal` option there (and corresponding command).  Which means you could use that command in a keybinding like so:

```
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "openInTerminal"
}
```

But my first `sendSequence` keybinding remains the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Only keybinding is correct here as other options all create new terminal, not change folder in existing one.

Comment: In keybindings.json.  Open the Keyboard Shortcuts from  the Gear icon in lower left.  Then click on the icon in the upper left (just to the left of the split editor icon) that opens keybindings.json.

Comment: I get `cd '${fileDirname}'
bash: cd: ${fileDirname}: No such file or directory` ?

Comment: Hmm, I use it everyday on bash, no problems.   You are using the `Original Answer`  code above?  It has to be used like that - through a `sendSequence` command so that the variable `${fileDirname}` can be resolved.

Comment: `sendSequence` works on my local project, but failed on vscode remote project, the error is `'${fileDirname}' can not be resolved. Please open an editor.` but the `newWithCwd ` command works both local and remove environment. It's might be a bug?

Comment: where in the world i will put above json?

Comment: @sairfan They are all keybindings, so keybindings.json.  `Command Palette/Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`

Comment: Thanks I'm new to VS Code did not understand what's going on there, thanks for help.

Comment: I do not see one for `workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd`. I dont see a way to add it either?  do i even have a keybindings.json?

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to simply add the following to VS Code Settings so that whatever key you have set for opening a new integrated terminal, it ensured that the terminal went to the directory of the currently opened file. This works regardless of the **new** terminal you select, be it powershell, CMD, Git Bash etc:

```
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

Comment: Its already set that way by default and it works only after VS is loaded, first terminal is still in $HOME.

Answer (score 2):

With Code Runner and Ctrl+Alt+N command you can have it solved by creating a batch file and passing the `${fileDirname}` value to the PowerShell 6 e.g like this:

1. Adding/changing those two lines in VSCode `settings.json`:

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6\\pwsh.bat",
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["${fileDirname}"]
   ```
2. Having such a `pwsh.bat` saved in the `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\` folder:

   ```
   @echo off
   set arg1=%1
   "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe" -noexit -Command "cd '%arg1%'"
   ```

**EDIT**

Small improvement to the batch file code useful when no file is opened and we still want to open a new Terminal:

````
```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
if [%arg1%] == [${fileDirname}] set arg1=
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe" -noexit -Command "cd '%arg1%'"
```
````

Answer (score 1):

As of at least v2022.6.1 of the Visual Studio Code [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell):

- [Darren Evans' helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1669123/darren-evans) shows how to customize the startup directory for *general-purpose shells* running in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.
- To customize the startup dir. for the *PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console)* - a *specialized* shell that comes with the PowerShell extension - use its analogous setting:

  - Via the GUI:

    - Open the Settings GUI via <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>
    - Locate setting `PowerShell: Cwd`
    - Specify `${fileDirname}` as the value.
  - Via the `settings.json` file:

    ```
    "powershell.cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, sorry for necroing it, but gonna answer either way for those stumbling here from Google.

If you want new terminals to open in your currently selected directory, open VSCode settings JSON, and add this line (or replace the one with the same key):

`"terminal.integrated.cwd": "./",`