# VS Code - Shortcut to change the current directory in the PowerShell console to the currently opened file?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am running the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) in Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell Integrated Console attached. I have two PowerShell scripts each open in separate tabs. The files are located in different directories.

I would like to quickly change the current directory to the currently active tab in the PowerShell console using a keyboard shortcut (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+D).

How does one accomplish this?

Comment: Did you see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218958/how-to-quickly-change-shell-folder-to-match-the-currently-open-file/56222855#56222855 and does it work for you?

Comment: @Mark I did not see that, and with a small tweak it works great in the PowerShell console as well as cmd. It needs the /d switch in case the drive letter changes, and it needs escaped double quotes for cmd. {"text": "cd /d \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"} How do I give you credit for a better answer?

Comment: Scratch the "/d" parameter. It doesn't work in the PowerShell console. {"text": "cd \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"} I upvoted the answer you linked.

Comment: In a normal cmd console (not PowerShell), if you are in the C:\ and you type "cd Z:\" it does *not* change the current directory. If you add the /d parameter, it does. Unfortunately, the /d parameter throws an error in the PowerShell console, so I removed it.

Comment: Since it is largely a duplicate question I am happy with an upvote to the original answer.  You should edit your answer below (and probably the github issue) to add the new changes that you discovered - and I will edit my answer to link to your answer then).  I understand your tweaks now - I tested it in Powershell and bash, but not changing to a different drive directory altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: This is the best solution so far**

(Thanks to Mark in the comments of the original post.)

In the keybindings.json file, add the following key binding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {"text": "cd \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"}
}
```

This works in both cmd and PowerShell consoles.
(The only flaw is that it does not change the directory across drives for the cmd console only).

---

**UPDATE 2**:

A new command will be added in **v1.39** `workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd`, see [add terminal here command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/79863). The example keybinding given is:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+h",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
    "args": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
}
```

This will create a new terminal, not change the current terminal.

---

**Previous answer**

Credit goes to [SeeminglyScience](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/2189) for this answer.

There is not currently a way to set a *keyboard* shortcut, but since that is not explicitly stated in the title, I will post another shortcut.

1. If you do not already have a file called **Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1** in your "*%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell*" directory, create one.
2. Create a custom PowerShell editor command by adding the following to the **Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1** file:

   ```
   Register-EditorCommand -Name 'ChangeDirHere' -DisplayName 'Change to the Directory of the Current File' -ScriptBlock {
       Set-Location ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($psEditor.GetEditorContext().CurrentFile.Path))
   }
   ```
3. Restart VS Code.
4. Open any PowerShell file.
5. Press Alt+Shift+S (or whatever keybinding you have for "Powershell: Show Additional Commands from PowerShell Modules").
6. Select the custom command from the drop-down list of PowerShell commands.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218958/how-to-quickly-change-shell-folder-to-match-the-currently-open-file/56222855#56222855 for an update.  A new command is being added that will make this even easier.