# Go to current path in Console or PowerShell Terminal in VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, command-prompt

**Quick Question:** Is there a shortcut key or an add-on for VS Code that updates the path in the integrated terminal to the path of the file that is currently open??

**For example:** Powershell in the integrated terminal always opens in my `C:\Users\andy` folder, but if I have a script in say `c:\scripts\powershell\superdooperhacks\andysscript\` I need to `cd` through a lot of folders to get there (or prepend the command with the entire path).

The only *quick* way I found so far is to right click on the file and `Reveal in Explorer` and then open another Powershell session by right-clicking and... you get the idea. That means, I now have three windows open and it defeats the purpose of having an *integrated* shell.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218958/how-to-quickly-change-shell-folder-to-match-the-currently-open-file/56222855#56222855 No need for an extension anymore.  Use the `sendSequence` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Terminal Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here) add-on. Exposes the command `terminalHere.create` that creates a terminal at the current file's directory. This can be accessed through the command palette (ctrl/cmd+shift+p) or by attaching a custom keybinding to it.

Comment: While this extension is handy, note that it always creates a _new_ shell in the integrated terminal, which won't be an integrated _PowerShell_ terminal (even if your default shell is PowerShell, a regularly launched instance will behave differently).

Comment: That's right, if we start some operation in the old terminal window and open a new terminal with this add-on, the old terminal will still perform the operation. Thanks for the addition.