# How do I get Visual Studio Code to run from the directory of the Python file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code. I am using Windows.

When I hit the "Run Code" button at the top right, I want my .py file to run from the current directory.

When I hit Run right now, I get the **Terminal window > Windows Powershell**, which prints:

```
PS C:\Users\zack> python -u "c:\Users\zack\Desktop\test.py"
```

In other words, I want the .py file to run as if I did "cmd" then "cd directory".

[I saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218958/how-to-quickly-change-shell-folder-to-match-the-currently-open-file) but I don't know where to type this.

[I also saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776521/python-in-vscode-set-working-directory-to-python-files-path-everytime) and enabled **Execute in File Dir**. Didn't change anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56776620/9938317 set the `cwd` property to the dir of the file

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for the response. Where is the launch.json file located?

Comment: if you use a program do you read the docs, or do a search with your favorite search engine